# How can I load a different android xml layout when the touch event of a surfaceview has been triggered

Tags: android

I have a GameView class, which extends Surface view and I load it in my activity

```
public class GameViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(new GameView());
}
```

In my GameView class, I have an ontouch listener

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


    GameTile tile = gridView.getTile(event.getX(), event.getY());

    tile.setGameTile(new EmptyStruckTile());

    drawGameView();

    return true;
}
```

In this onTouch method, once a touch event has been triggered and objects are drawn onto the view, the user should be redirected to a different xml layout. My question is, how can I cause my activity, after a touch event has been triggered in the surface view, that has currently been loaded with setContentView(new GameView(), to wait accordingly to some timeout value and load a different xml layout file?
And bear in mind, I should be able to at some point go back to the surface view.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy by inflating some layout and work with them. For example you can create it using multiple PopupView.

You have you activity, with SurfaceView. Some action is happened and trigger call your functions below.

**Base initialize:**

```
SurfaceView yourSurfaceView;
PopupView popupViewPause;
```

**Function to show Pause menu:**

```
showPauseMenu () {
LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
     = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
      .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
    popupViewPause = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup1, null);  
             final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
               popupView, 
               LayoutParams.MATH_PARENT,  
                     LayoutParams.MATH_PARENT);  

             Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
             btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      popupWindow.dismiss();
     }});

     /* Initialize your other views, buttons from R.layout.popup1

      * ----------------------------------------------------
      */

             popupViewPause.showAsDropDown(yourSurfaceView, 0, 0);

   }});
}
```

**Function to close Pause menu:**

```
closePauseMenu () {
   if (popupViewPause != null) {
      popupViewPause.close();
   }
}
```

Repeat code above as many as you need with different layout.